# How to restructure an object show in message in jquery or in javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

Hi SO i've been struggling in this kind of situation. Maybe someone who can help me in this problem.

Attempted Code:

```
var Obj = {
   Type: {
   message: "This field is required"
 },
   Bonus1: {
   message: "This field is required"
 },
   Bonus2: {
   message: "This field is required"
 },
   Bonus3: {
   message: "This field is required"
 },
   Date: {
   message: "This field is required"
 },
   Time: {
   message: "This field is required"
 }
};

var message = "";

$.each(Obj, function(i, v){
 if(i.match(/Bonus/g))
 {
   i = i.concat(', ');
 }  
  message += i + ": " +v.message + "\n";
});

alert(message);
```

If two or more Bonus show this:

[image]

If One Bonus show this:

[image]

[JS Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/aldrin27/27095x45/)

Comment: See [ask] and **[mcve]**

Comment: @Tushar sorry for that. I don't know how to explain my problem. I'm having difficulty in showing the right message in alertbox.

Comment: @StephenMuecke Nope. I've posted the expected output.

Comment: @stdob-- It will add new line then message is index + " is invalid Bonus";

Comment: @aldrin27 In my opinion, you should describe the problem more clearly.

Comment: @stdob-- currently I don't know to describe it more clearly because I'm confused about it. If i'm going to restructure my object or maybe you can suggest me on how to achieved my expected output.

Comment: @stdob-- Thank you so much. Kindly make this answer and I'll accept it. And some brief explanation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1) Divide the key and key index using regular expressions:

```
var re = /([^0-9]*)([0-9]*)/; // The string ends with a number
var restruct = {};

$.each(Obj, function(i, v){
  var m;
  var index;
  if ((m = re.exec(i)) !== null) {
      if (m.index === re.lastIndex) {
          re.lastIndex++;
      }
  }
  i = m[1];
  index = m[2];
})
```

2) For each key save differing messages and their corresponding indexes:

```
  if (typeof restruct[i] === 'undefined') restruct[i] = {};
  if (typeof restruct[i][v.message] === 'undefined') restruct[i][v.message] = []
  if (index.length>0) restruct[i][v.message].push(index)
```

3) Construct the final message:

```
 $.each(restruct, function(i) {
     $.each(restruct[i], function(m,v){
        message += (v.join(',') + ' ' + i).trim() + ': ' + m + '\r\n';
     });
 });
```

[https://jsfiddle.net/1b9qum1d/]

Comment: Thank you again for helping me.